# Codeigniter PHPExcel reader displaying data very slow

Tags: codeigniter, phpexcel

I am using Codeigniter PHPExcel.

Basically i am using an excel files to read data and display it on the website through PHPExcel. Currently it is taking time to load.
What it basically is doing is creating JSON files through PHPExcel libraries and the data is being read through JSON once the page has been loaded.

But, I am facing a slow load now. When i went through the JSON file i saw that the size is around 3.5 MB and i have more than 3 files through which i am reading the data.

Can anyone suggest me any workarounds for the optimisation? I have read about "Reading in Chunks".

Can we read for the few rows for the first request, like basic filtering we generally do while fetching from database?

Answer (score 0):

May be you should use and DB to prevent loading files for many time? If you use JSON format - MongoDB or PostrgesQL (with json field) will be perfect. Or just parse fields from excel file and load this to normalized DB.